# How to set debuggable flag for chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova

In the official tutorial 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap
they say

Chrome Remote Debugging:
If you are using Cordova 3.3 or higher, this is already supported, and only requires the Debuggable flag in your AndroidManifest.xml
I put        in platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml
and get a build erro running build
Anyway, I thing it should be configured in the config.xml

Comment: Are you running phonegap locally or using phonegap build?

Comment: I run it on my phone. 
I realize that debugging only works when you have android 4.4 automatically. Otherwise, maybe remote debugging is not possible this way.

Comment: So, you saying that these are the requirements: Chrome 30 or later (on desktop), android 4.4 or later on the device, USB debugging enabled on the device, device connected by usb cable and debuggable flag in AndroidManifest.xml. Right? If that's the case, you can just answer your own question with that response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remote debugging using Chrome appear in embedded WebView on Android only starting from Android 4.0. More details on Google website:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

In Cordova itself, remote debugging land in 4.4 version

Comment: According the link provided, it begin from 4.0

Comment: That's true, but enabling of the remote debugging in Cordova Apps was start available from the 4.4 (https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/4a0a7bc424fae14c9689f4a8a2dc250ae3a47f82/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewEngine.java#L193)
The reason for that if I remember correctly is that enabling remote debugging was private API before that release